# How to install rust for jupyter on mac?

Tags: python, macos, rust, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I know Python well enough, and I wanted to learn a second languuage. I have the resources to learn Rust, but I need help in installing it. You see, I have Anaconda and Jupyter with obviously Python booted on them. I want to install rust as a Jupyter kernel so that I can learn Rust, and make games with it via Redox engine. But first I want to learn and experiment with Rust on Jupyter.

Comment: AFAIK there is no Rust REPL, so no way Rust could be used as a Jupyter kernel.

Comment: There is a [list of available kernels](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) both official and 3rd party. See if it has what you want and then try to follow the steps lined out to install it. I don't think the scope of this site would be to repeat what is provided in documentation already

Answer (score 4):

You can install rust for jupyter on mac with [Evcxr Jupyter Kernel](https://github.com/evcxr/evcxr/blob/main/evcxr_jupyter/README.md)

I follow the tutorial from [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UEMn3yUoLo&ab_channel=Dr.ShahinRostami)

1. Install miniconda/anaconda
2. Create and activate conda environment

```
conda create -n rustjupyter python=3.8
conda activate rustjupter
```

3. Install jupyterlab (1.1.4), cmake, nodejs (13.10.1)

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab==1.1.4
conda install -c anaconda cmake
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs=13.10.1
```

4. Install rust (1.68.0+)

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

5. Install evcxr_jupyter

```
cargo install evcxr_jupyter
evcxr_jupyter --install
```

6. Run jupyter lab

```
jupyter lab
```

7. Go to http://localhost:8888/ on browser, select **Rust** in *Notebook* section

[image]

8. Now you can run Rust on Jupyter

[image]

---

For more command usage information of Evcxr, follow the [document](https://github.com/evcxr/evcxr/blob/main/COMMON.md)